# Multiple ajax calls fired simultaneously not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I created a site which load every few seconds data from multiple sources via AJAX. However I experience some strange behavior. Here is the code:

```
function worker1() {
    var currentUrl = 'aaa.php?var=1';
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: currentUrl, 
        success: function(data) {                    
            alert(data)
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(worker1, 2000);
        }
    });
}

function worker2() {
    var currentUrl = 'aaa.php?var=2';
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: currentUrl, 
        success: function(data) {                    
            alert(data)
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(worker2, 2000);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that many times, one of the workers returns NaN. If I change the frequency of calls for, lets say, `2000` and `1900`, then everything is working ok and I got almost no `NaN` results. When those frequencies are same, I get over 80% `NaN` results for one of the calls. It seems like the browser cannot handle two requests called at exact same time. I use only those two workers, so the browser shouldn't be overloaded by AJAX requests. Where is the problem?

Note that the `aaa.php` works with the mySql database and do some simple queries base on parameters in url.

Comment: It's unlikely to be a browser issue. More likely it's a problem at the server which you need to investigate. It's possible if you have multiple requests being made to the same resource from the same location the connections will be throttled.

Comment: Could it be somehow connected to the aaa.php file and its connection to database?

Comment: Do you use session in these PHP methods ?

Comment: It's possible. Seeing the code of `aaa.php` would possibly help us to diagnose an issue.

Comment: I do not use sessions. The aaa.php is quite long and there are some sensitive data inside. Still the processing time of aaa.php should be minimal, as the tasks it does are very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is **[$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)** and the two parameter form of **[$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

```
var urls = ['/url/one','/url/two', ....];

$.each(urls, function(i,u){ 
     $.ajax(u, 
       { type: 'POST',
         data: {
            answer_service: answer,
            expertise_service: expertise,
            email_service: email,
         },
         success: function (data) {
             $(".anydivclass").text(data);
         } 
       }
     );
});
```

> Note: The messages generated by the success callback will overwrite
>   each other as shown. You'll probably want to use
>   $('#divid').append() or similar in the success function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, don't use these workers and use promises instead like below?  Can't say anything about the errors being returned though without looking at the server code.  Below is working code for what it looks like you are trying to do.

This is a simple example but you could use different resolvers for each url with an object ({url:resolverFunc}) and then iterate using Object.keys.

```js
var urls = [
  'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1',
  'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2',
  'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3',
  'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/4',
  'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/5',
  'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/6',
  'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/7'
]

function multiGet(arr) {
  var promises = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    promises.push($.get(arr[i])
      .then(function(res) {
        // Do something with each response
        console.log(res);
      })
    );
  }
  return $.when(promises);
}

multiGet(urls);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```